# How can I get the current class of a div with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, how can I get the current class of a div called `div1`?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Just get the class attribute:

```
var div1Class = $('#div1').attr('class');
```

Example

```
<div id="div1" class="accordion accordion_active">
```

To check the above div for classes contained in it

```
var a = ("#div1").attr('class'); 
console.log(a);
```

console output

```
accordion accordion_active
```

Comment: is that really an attribute? `className`..? Isn't `className` only used for javascript? `document.getElementById("div1").className`

Comment: Saw now that according to the jQuery doc it's suggested to use `className` so it won't interfere with the reserved word `class` in javascript...

Comment: **NOTE:** In jQuery 1.6, they *finally* fixed the `attr` method, and you should now use `$(...).attr('class');`, `className` is just an accessor property that maps to the `class` attribute on the DOM element -there is no `className` attribute, it's just a property-.

Answer (score 19):

Simply by

```
var divClass = $("#div1").attr("class")
```

You can do some other stuff to manipulate element's class

```
$("#div1").addClass("foo"); // add class 'foo' to div1
$("#div1").removeClass("foo"); // remove class 'foo' from div1
$("#div1").toggleClass("foo"); // toggle class 'foo'
```

Answer (score 13):

```
$('#div1').attr('class')
```

will return a string of the classes. Turn it into an array of class names

```
var classNames = $('#div1').attr('class').split(' ');
```

Comment: +1'd.  ($('#div1').attr('class') || '').split(' ') is safer imo.

Answer (score 10):

From now on is better to use the .prop() function instead of the .attr() one.

Here the jQuery documentation:

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes
>   that have not been set. In addition, .attr() should not be used on
>   plain objects, arrays, the window, or the document. To retrieve and
>   change DOM properties, use the .prop() method.

```
var div1Class = $('#div1').prop('class');
```

Comment: it's changed again since 2.2:   _As of jQuery 1.12/2.2, [...] the class attribute is used instead. So, .removeClass() can be used on XML or SVG documents._ (source: https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#div1").attr("class")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var classname=$('#div1').attr('class')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var className=$('selector').attr('class');
```

or

```
var className=$(this).attr('class');
```

the classname of the current element

Answer (score 1):

The addClass method in jQuery has a `currentClass` built in property. You can use it inside a function call. Like so:

```
<div>First div</div>
<div class="red">Second div</div>
<div>Third div</div>
<div>Fourth div</div>

<script>
  $("div").addClass(function(index, currentClass) {
    var addedClass;
    if ( currentClass === "red" ) {
      addedClass = "green"; }
    return addedClass;
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

$("#div1").attr("class")

Answer (score 0):

```
<div  id="my_id" class="my_class"></div>
```

if that is the first div then address it like so:

```
document.write("div CSS class: " + document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].className);
```

alternatively do this:

```
document.write("alternative way: " + document.getElementById('my_id').className);
```

It yields the following results:

```
div CSS class: my_class
alternative way: my_class
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to look for a div that has more than 1 class try this:

Html:

```
<div class="class1 class2 class3" id="myDiv">
```

Jquery:

```
var check = $( "#myDiv" ).hasClass( "class2" ).toString();
```

ouput:

`true`