# Getting the class(s) of a div using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Well I already saw this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536117/how-can-i-get-the-current-css-class-of-a-div-with-jquery). But m a little bit of confused. There were several solutions provided:-

1. `var div1Class = $('#div1').attr('className');`

   This one was the accepted solution with 2 up votes.
2. `var divClass = $("#div1").attr("class")`

   This got an up vote too.

Which is the correct one? And if both are correct, what is the difference between the two?

Comment: If you only want to test if an element has a particular class name, consider using jQuery's `is` method - `$("#div1").is(".some-class")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's permissible to use 'class', jQuery will fix it,
but jQuery recommands to use 'className' [Attributes/attr](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr)

to avoid collision with classes definition, DOM renamed 'class' attribute to 'className'.
same thing for the 'for' attribute that was renamed 'htmlFor'. (see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html) :1.6.2. Naming Exceptions)

Answer (score 3):

There is no HTML attribute `className` - the correct code is:

```
var divClass = $("#div1").attr("class");
```

`className` is a Javascript DOM property, so if you weren't using jQuery you could do:

```
var divClass = document.getElementById('div1').className;
```

Comment: well, className option was the accepted solution on the link to the question I provided !!

Comment: I have always used 'class', but yes, it seems najmeddine is right in his answer too (or actually, we are both right): http://www.nabble.com/class-or-className-td5219071s27240.html

Comment: Yes, I guess he's more correct..!! :-) So marking his answer as the solution