# How to get the class of all elements with certain id in jquery

Tags: jquery, class

Hi I know this is probably super easy, but at this moment I am having a brain fart! I need to get the class of all elements with x id. And then I need to print out those class names. Example:

HTML:

```
<div class="picture"><img src="one.jpg" class="one.jpg" id="yes"></picture>
<div class="picture"><img src="ones.jpg" class="ones.jpg" id="no"></picture>
<div class="picture"><img src="oned.jpg" class="oned.jpg" id="yes"></picture>
<div class="picture"><img src="onez.jpg" class="onez.jpg" id="yes"></picture>
<div class="selected"></div>
```

JQUERY:

```
var selectedImg = $(".picutre img").attr("id","yes").class();
    $(".selected").html(selectedImg);
```

Comment: In `html` you must have just one unique id per element.

Comment: Id should be unique.  You shouldn't have duplicates.  This could confuse your scripts.  You could go with the `name` attribute instead.

Comment: possibly answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536117/how-can-i-get-the-current-class-of-a-div-with-jquery

Comment: According to the HTML spec, IDs must be unique. You should be using a "data-" attribute or a second class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your Ids must be unique.
Then, there is no method 'class' in jQuery. I would advise you to use [HTML5 data](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) with jQuery.

HTML :

```
<div class="picture">
    <img src="test.jpg" class="one.jpg" data-bool="yes" />
    <img src="test.jpg" class="ones.jpg" data-bool="no" />
    <img src="test.jpg" class="oned.jpg" data-bool="yes" />
    <img src="test.jpg" class="onez.jpg" data-bool="yes" />
</div>
<div class="selected"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.picture img').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.data('bool') == 'yes'){
        $('.selected').append($this.attr('class'));
    }
});`
```

Hope it was usefull !

Answer (score 2):

Using the same `id` on multiple elements in the same DOM is invalid.  You should change this now!  This prevents you from getting the jQuery ID selector (`#`) to work the way you want.  However, the attr selector will still work (`".picture img[id=yes]"`).

jQuery has no `.class()` method.  To get the class, you need to use `.attr('class')`.

Keep in mind that if you call a method on a selector, you will only get the *first* element found by that selector.  That is, `$(".picture img[id=yes]").attr('class')` will return `one.jpg` even though there are multiple elements that match that selector.

By the way, you misspelled picture.

Comment: Using mutiple elements with same ID's is against HTML policy of having unique ID in a html page. What answer given here in this answer is the most correct one. Try this fiddle which is similiar to the question - http://jsfiddle.net/harshithjv/uSN3c/

Answer (score 1):

**Id must be unique!**

So the answer is easy:

```
var class = $('#x').attr('class');
```

If you select all the images with `$('img')` selector you can alert them all with `each` function:

```
$('img').each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uKKd4/)
​

- Note that when you have a `div` with picture class like you do: `<div class="picture">` you don't close it with `</picture>` You close it with `</div>`

Answer (score 1):

All id's in an HTML document must be unique. You might want to use data-id to save that date in the URL's. To get the class for each selected image with a `data-id="yes"` you might do this:

`var selectedImg = $('img[data-id="yes"]').attr('class');`