# JQuery - Get the CSS class of an element

Tags: jquery

I have an anchor as follows:

```
<a href="#" class="Menu">Text</a>
```

How can I get the CSS Class of this anchor using JQuery?

So in this case I would get "Menu".

I am able to add and remove CSS classes but I can't find a way to get the CSS classes of an element. What can I do ?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536117/how-can-i-get-the-current-class-of-a-div-with-jquery

Comment: I won't vote as duplicate as the linked answers mainly use the slow solution (that is `attr`) instead of the native property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [the native property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.className) :

```
$(selectorOrElement).get(0).className
```

Note that it's often answered to use `attr('class')`. Not only is there no gain in using a complex function instead of the native DOM property but it's also, quite naturally, much slower. See [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-attr-class-vs-js-classname/2)