# Get CSS classes from jQuery object

Tags: jquery, css

The only results I can find talking about this are over 6 years old so I figured this might have been updated since.

If I have a jQuery object

```
var myObj = $("#anObj");
```

Is there a simple way to see what CSS classes are defined for that object?

(I am asking as I am getting an element object as part of a callback and not entirely sure how to read and alter the classes)

Comment: `myObj.attr('class')`???

Comment: `myObj.css()` will get you the computed styles: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the current class of a div with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536117/how-can-i-get-the-current-class-of-a-div-with-jquery)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536117/how-can-i-get-the-current-class-of-a-div-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the class attribute for the element. It will will return its value which will have the classes in.

```
var theClasses = $("#anObj").attr("class");
```

Comment: It works!  My Google skills are weak today.  Thanks for helping me out :)

Comment: @Guerrilla accept the answer, also you should look into the jQuery documentation if you are worried about whether it's still true today. I say that because jQuery actually does a good job of helping you find this information easily.

Comment: @AGE There is a time limit, you are not able to immediately accept it.  I looked at documentastion but I misunderstood what is said for attr, i thought it meant it was only able to set because this is what the old threads i read said I just made a wrong assumption

Comment: That's ok, we are here to help anyways

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myObj = $("#x").css("background-color");
    $("#x").html("<p>"+myObj+"</p>");
});
```

```css
#x {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: #666;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="x"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi, the [.css function](http://api.jquery.com/css/) of JQuery is the right way.
See code snippet.